# SQL/Big Query: impute nulls using another table

Tags: google-bigquery, imputation

I have the following table structure, one row for each store and for every 15 minutes:

data_table:

| time | weekday | hour | store | purchase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-23 10:00:00 | 1 | 10 | S1 | 100 |
| 2022-01-23 10:00:00 | 1 | 10 | S2 | 50 |
| 2022-01-23 10:00:00 | 1 | 10 | S3 | 2 |
| 2022-01-23 10:15:00 | 1 | 10 | S1 | null |
| 2022-01-23 10:15:00 | 1 | 10 | S2 | 120 |
| 2022-01-23 10:15:00 | 1 | 10 | S3 | 30 |
| 2022-01-23 10:30:00 | 1 | 10 | S1 | 5 |
| 2022-01-23 10:30:00 | 1 | 10 | S2 | null |
| 2022-01-23 10:30:00 | 1 | 10 | S3 | 50 |

I want to impute all the null values in the purchase column in data_table using purchase column from imputation_table, on the basis of the same weekday, hour and store. The two tables have different shapes, imputation_table contains only the possible combinations of weekday, hour and store and a value for purchase.

imputation_table:

| weekday | hour | store | purchase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | S1 | 75.5 |
| 1 | 10 | S2 | 35 |
| 1 | 10 | S3 | 5 |
| 1 | 11 | S1 | 80 |
| 1 | 11 | S2 | 95.5 |
| 1 | 11 | S3 | 25 |
| 1 | 12 | S1 | 90.5 |
| 1 | 12 | S2 | 10 |
| 1 | 12 | S3 | 45 |

For example, the first null in the data_table should be imputed with 75.5 from the imputation_table (weekday=1, hour=10 and store=S1) and the 2nd null with 35 (weekday=1, hour=10 and store=S2).

How should I do this in SQL (Big Query)?

Answer (score 2):

With the data you provided try the following:

```
select
  dt.time,
  dt.weekday,
  dt.hour,
  dt.store,
  ifnull(dt.purchase, it.purchase)
from data_table dt
left join imputation_table it
 on dt.weekday=it.weekday
 and dt.hour=it.hour
 and dt.store=it.store
```

This results in the following:

[image]

[IFNULL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#ifnull) allows to replace the value if the provided value is null.  In this scenario if purchase from the data table is null it returns the imputation purchase value.  The main key is joining the two tables so it can have a result to match to.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below slim version

```
select d.* replace(ifnull(d.purchase, i.purchase) as purchase)
from data_table d
left join imputation_table i
using (weekday, hour, store)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]